# Trouble loading tiff images with wxWidgets when using camera aquisition methods

Tags: c++, visual-c++, wxwidgets, tiff

I am writing (or rather taking over) a little network camera capture program that was written in Visual C++.  The camera is an Allied Vision Technologies and uses the `PvAPI.h`, and the GUi was written in `wxwidgets`. The project was abandoned when they couldn't get tiff images to load under wxWidgets. I have traced the problem down to a single line, sadly it is the line where the frame is captured off the camera

```
if( !ImageWriteTiff(GCamera.Filename,pFrame) )
```

if I comment out this line the following line works fine

```
image = new wxStaticBitmap(mainPanel, wxID_ANY, wxBitmap("C:\\path-to\\horse.tif",
    wxBITMAP_TYPE_TIF), wxPoint(244,64));
```

For some reason if I use `ImageWriteTiff` is doesn't allow wxWidgets to import a tiff.  I also make sure to import all image handlers

```
wxInitAllImageHandlers();
```

Comment: 'doesn't allow wxWidgets to import a tiff'  What does this mean?  Do you get an error message, does the program crash, what?

Comment: when i run a compiled version, Visual C++ says "TIFF: Error Reading image" and under details it says "tiff module: image" "Sorry, requested compression method is not configured" "TIFF: Error reading image."

Comment: I suggest adding these details to your question so everyone can read them easily.

Answer (score 0):

They probably have the TIFF library built without support for compression.  IIRC, it's not turned on by default.

As a test, try loading the TIFF into a free paint program like the Gimp and save it out uncompressed and see if your wx loading code works.

If that is the problem, then you need to rebuild your wx library with zlib as part of the tiff library.  Since this is OS/compiler dependent you need to google that.  Also, it might be that the version of wx is out of date.